# JSON receiving data from android

Tags: php, android, json, http, post

I am new to php. I am posting data to php server from android as--

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try
{
    jsonObject.put("name", "john");
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/WebService/submitname.php";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("json", jsonObject.toString());
    StringEntity se = null;
    se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(
    HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    int i = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.v("status", "" + i);
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And receiving the data in php as

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("my db");
 $var = json_decode($_POST['HTTP_JSON']);
 $service = $var->{'name'};
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO name_table(`_id`, `retrived_name`, `cat`, `is_valid_name`) VALUES (1547, '$service','$var',true);");
 echo  $var;
?>
```

Getting nothing on server side. However php query is executing correct as getting 200 response and a new row in database but with empty  `retrived_name` and `cat` field.

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You Should provide the values in Query:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("my db");
    $var = json_decode($_POST['HTTP_JSON']);
    $service = $var->{'name'};
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO name_table(`_id`, `retrived_name`, `cat`, `is_valid_name`) VALUES (1547, '$service','$name',true);");
    echo  $var;
?>
```